# How to get Hours difference between login and logout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get time in hours and the hour difference between login and logout times?

I used the below query:

```
select LoginDateTime,LogoutDateTime from Fleet_DriverQueueList
```

I have attached a screenshot of my data below.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the query you've used to get the above result set?

Comment: What output you expect if the `LogoutDateTime` is `NULL`? Mean you want to add any fixed hours from the `LoginDateTime` if the `LogoutDateTime` value is `NULL`?

Comment: Is the above info of a single user?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT ISNULL(DATEDIFF(HOUR, LoginDateTime, LogoutDateTime), 1) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the DATEDIFF function. Like this:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(HOUR,[LoginDateTime],[LogoutDateTime])
FROM
    YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) with minutes or even seconds it will be more accurate:

```
select  DATEDIFF(minute,LoginDateTime,COALESCE(LogoutDateTime,GETDATE()))/60.00,
        CASE WHEN LogoutDateTime IS NULL THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Not Active' END [Status]
from Fleet_DriverQueueList

select  DATEDIFF(second,LoginDateTime,COALESCE(LogoutDateTime,GETDATE()))/3600.00,
        CASE WHEN LogoutDateTime IS NULL THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Not Active' END [Status]
from Fleet_DriverQueueList

select  DATEDIFF(hour,LoginDateTime,COALESCE(LogoutDateTime,GETDATE()))/3600.00,
        CASE WHEN LogoutDateTime IS NULL THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Not Active' END [Status]
from Fleet_DriverQueueList
```

Comment: Check my answer, please. If you found any of answers helpful, feel free to upvote/accept them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Datediff function, try this

```
Select Case when isnull(LogoutDateTime,'')='' then 'Active' else 'Not Active' end as Status, 
Case when isnull(LogoutDateTime,'')='' 
     then DATEDIFF(HH,LoginDateTime,getdate()) 
     else DATEDIFF(HH,LoginDateTime,LogoutDateTime) end as Period 
from Fleet_DriverQueueList
```

Comment: can you please help me how to get if driver active getdate() and show Time of Hours